# Completion handler not firing dongri/OAuthSwift

Tags: swift, oauth

I am having difficulty implementing OAuth2 into my swift project. I am currently using https://github.com/dongri/OAuthSwift and while I can successfully Authorize the user I can't get the completion handler to fire, for example if I were to include a `println()` method in either the success or failure block nothing prints to the console. If anyone can help me out with this that would be awesome.

// OAuth2.0

```
    oauthswift.authorize_url_handler = webViewController()
    let state: String = generateStateWithLength(20) as String


    oauthswift.authorizeWithCallbackURL(NSURL(string: "oauth-swift://oauth-callback/github")!, scope: "user,repo", state: state,
        success: {(credential: OAuthSwiftCredential, response: NSURLResponse?, parameters: NSDictionary) in


            println("success")

        },
        failure: {(error: NSError) -> Void in
            println("fail")
    })
```